# Update .net 5 to .net 6 redis issue

Tags: c#, .net, redis, .net-6.0

I have just updated my .net5 application to .net6 and I'm getting the following error when I try to connect to redis:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: Sentinel: Failed connecting to configured master for service: redis://f69458f1-e65f-4f26-8c22-ec9015aaa4fb
> at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.GetSentinelMasterConnection(ConfigurationOptions config, TextWriter log) in /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2377
> at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.SentinelMasterConnect(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log) in /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1100
> at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log) in /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1029
> at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String configuration, TextWriter log) in /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1015
> at Project.Redis.RedisConnection.<>c.b__3_0() in E:\BA\02\6\s\source\Project\Redis\RedisConnection.cs:line 18
> at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
> at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
> at Project.Redis.RedisConnection.get_Connection() in E:\BA\02\6\s\source\Project\Redis\RedisConnection.cs:line 11
> at Project.BackgroundServices.MessageReceiver.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in E:\BA\02\6\s\source\Project\BackgroundServices\MessageReceiver.cs:line 31
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
> at Project.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\BA\02\6\s\source\Project\Program.cs:line 22

I have created the following RedisConnection class:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace Project.Redis
{
    public static class RedisConnection
    {
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> _lazyConnection = CreateConnection();

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection => _lazyConnection.Value;

        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> CreateConnection()
        {
            return new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
            {
                string connectionString = BuildRedisConnectionString();
                return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
            });
        }

        private static string BuildRedisConnectionString()
        {
            JObject parsedAppCloudSettings = XXXX;
            JToken redisCredentials = parsedAppCloudSettings["redis"].First["credentials"];
            string master = redisCredentials["master"].Value<string>();
            string host = redisCredentials["host"].Value<string>();
            string password = redisCredentials["password"].Value<string>();
            return $"{host},serviceName={master},password={password}";
        }
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

- Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchagneRedis 6.0.3
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis 6.0.3

Does anyone know what is causing this error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/2.5.43 looks like it supports till .net5

Comment: Yes, but I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis - @ashwathmabiyan

Answer (score 0):

The error was fixed after removing "redis://" from service name: "redis://f69458f1-e65f-4f26-8c22-ec9015aaa4fb"

Comment: Are you not running into issues using StackExchange.Redis in net6? They have not added support for net 6 yet and it is not working for me